# Free Pascal Execute Byte Array as Function

Tags: assembly, freepascal

I have a small function that do some small calculations (no external calls or strings), I've dumped the function from the memory to a Byte Array.
Now I'm trying to call the address pointed from the byte array but I'm getting Access Violation, I think the problem is the approach I'm using:

```
type TFunc = function (input: Pointer): Integer;
...
procedure execute;
const
  Buffer: array[0..287] of Byte = ($55, $48, ...)
var
  Callable: TFunc;
  output: Integer;
begin
  Callable := TFunc(@Buffer);
  i := Callable(somePointer);
  ...
end;
```

I have tested the function before convert it to byte array and it works properly. I also can't assign directly the pointer to "Callable".
The access violation occurs only on the call.
Is it possible to do it with only free pascal or do I need an asm for the call? If so how can I pass parameters and get the result?
I would also need passing an array for another function does it is different?
Thanks

Comment: Use VirtualAlloc to allocate executable memory. Or better, use the built in assembler.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for VirtualAlloc for Linux? I need it to be cross-platform. Using Assembler x86 registers (EAX...) will work also for all x64 platforms, or do I need to compile it again?

Comment: There will be an equivalent on Linux, I don't know what it is. For x64 there is a different ABI than x86, different between Linux and Windows, so you likely need different versions.

Comment: If I understand it correctly the problem is only that the memory where the byte array is stored is non-executable. In free pascal docs I've seen AllocMem but it writes on the Heap, but there is also Sptr which points to current stack position, is it possible to execute it as code if I allocate the byte array into the stack? The heap can be set as executable? I've read about heap-based buffer overflows that run code

Comment: `mmap` and `mprotect`

Comment: You want this to be cross-platform? Note that assembler doesn't easily carry over to other platforms, even if they use the same CPU and bitness. Some platforms require aligned stacks, or position independent code while others don't, system calls are totally different, etc.etc., but also the ABIs are different, i.e. arguments are passed differently (stack, different registers, FPU stack, MMU registers, and so on), with perhaps different alignment, etc.etc. If you want to do this, use the assembler and conditional compilation.

Comment: Now, if you have a different bitness, the calling convetion may be different, and arguments are passed differently (not just the sizes of the registers, but also **different** registers, or on the stack, with different offsets, etc. etc.). In general, unless it is *extremely* trivial, machine code as a set of bytes can not so easily be re-used on a different platform.

Comment: Yes it is true, I wanted to avoid Assembler because of this. So I will create different procedures for at least Windows and Linux systems also for x64. Thanks anyway to all of you :)